# How should I remove subset variable X from column names of my data?

Tags: r

I have subsetted data from a large file and find X added to each column name of the data. I write the data using write.csv, opened externally and removed X from every column manually and saved the file. Now  when I read this file again, the X is still there in column names. Example: X2001, X2002, X2004 etc.

Answer (score 4):

You can check the difference here:

```
 dat1 <- read.table(text="2001 2002
 45 32
 46 35",sep="",header=TRUE)
```

and

```
 dat2<- read.table(text="2001 2002
 45 32
 46 35",sep="",header=TRUE, check.names=FALSE)


 colnames(dat1)  #it is because by default `R` doesn't allow colnames that start with numbers
 #[1] "X2001" "X2002"
 colnames(dat2)
 #[1] "2001" "2002"
```

I would say that it would be better not to use `check.names=FALSE` because

```
  dat2$2001
  #Error: unexpected numeric constant in "dat2$2001"
```

but of course you can use `backticks` to avoid the error

```
  dat2$`2001`
  #[1] 45 46
```

#### Update

In the `read.table` code, the `make.names` argument is creating the `X`

```
    if (check.names) 
    col.names <- make.names(col.names, unique = TRUE)
```

For example:

```
   make.names(c("2001", "2002"), unique=TRUE)
   #[1] "X2001" "X2002"
```

Comment: But this solution is temporary(just for reading file). How can I solve this permanently. So that I don't need to use check.names everytime I read the file?

Comment: @Gaurav Chawla using `check.names` is the most straightforward way.  I am not sure what you mean by solving it permanently?.

Comment: Permanently means as I have stated/described in the question details. Even when I try to delete the X manually(externally) and save the file, still it reads X (without using check.names)

Comment: @Gaurav Chawla In that case, you have to change the code of `read.table` because `check.names` use `make.names`.  I don't understand why passing a check.names argument in the `read.table` is so difficult, though?

Answer (score 1):

Guarav, if you do not want to stay setting `check.names` all the time, wrap `read.table` (I wouldn't suggest modifying the `read.table` code itself).

```
read.table.raw.names <- function(...) {
   args <- list(...)
   if ("check.names" %in% names(args)) stop("Function does not require check.names to be set")
   read.table(...,check.names=F)
}
```

Then, following on akrun's example

```
dat1 <- read.table.raw.names(text="2001 2002
45 32
46 35",sep="",header=TRUE)

colnames(dat1)
#[1] "2001" "2002"
```

Comment: +1, It seems the OP wants less typing.  In that case, the name of wrapping function could be shorter.